# Javascript if/else statements, defining and returning variables?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, return

I'm trying to work on a rock/paper/scissors type game and there's a block of code that doesn't seem to work. There don't seem to be any syntax errors, at least to my eye or knowledge, but the console keeps coming up blank. This is what I came up with - to make it easier I started off by comparing numbers instead of 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors'.

```
function getWinner(a, b) {   
    var winner;
    if (a === b) {
        winner = 'tie';
    } else if (a > b) {
        winner = 'adam';
    } else if (b > a) {
        winner = 'bob';
    }
    return winner;
}
```

Please tell me if you see anything wrong or things that could be written better! I'm trying to keep the return statement separate from the if statements.

Comment: `a = ;` is a syntax error.

Comment: Why do you declare arguments `a` and `b`, but then assign values to both of them?  This negates any use of passing in the arguments.

Comment: How are you using this code? You say that "the console keeps coming up blank" but I don't see any calls that log anything to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid syntax in `a = ;` and `b = ;`. Just remove those invalid lines and you should be fine:

```
function getWinner(a, b) {
    var winner;
    if (a === b) {
        winner = 'tie';
    } else if (a > b) {
        winner = 'adam';
    } else if (b > a) {
        winner = 'bob';
    }
    return winner;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below.

```
function getWinner(a, b) {   
    var winner;
    if (a === b) {
        winner = 'tie';
    } else if (a > b) {
        winner = 'adam';
    } else {
        winner = 'bob';
    }
    return winner;
}
```

Because if you comparing a with b and then check for a is greater then b the last option is always the winner.